# Why get token not working in twilio chat JS

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-php

i was just using the twilio chat library for JS when i run in localhost tried login as guest.i am getting this error :

```
http://localhost:81/getToken?identity=frend&endpointId=394c15ba68f92e147e827c08b54799e1 404 Not Found
```

my path to directory was

```
http://localhost:81/JSCli/twilio-chat-demo-js-master/public/
```

but its redirecting to above one in twilio chat demo js .can anyone help me on this.thanks in advance.

Comment: 404 not found means exactly that. Not found. Your path is in a sub-directory /JSCli whereas it is looking for getToken in the root. Update your configuration and tell it it's running in a sub directory so the references are generated properly. Otherwise, follow the tutorial EXACTLY.

Comment: Yes.i got that..but why that is pointing to root directory i didnt find ant get token api in directory from where it is refrring i want to know.this is twilio chat demo js lib.kindly can you help me on this.

Comment: RTFM please or ask the developers why their program sucks

Comment: Are you using one of the quickstarts? Can you tell me which one? Thanks!

Comment: yea i am using twili javascript chat demo    
    [link] https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-js

Answer (score 0):

that /gettoken doesn't exists in the library which we'll download from github twilio js chat demo.
we have to create a file which will generate the access token for twilio operations.